# Invalid utf8 input detected on Smalltalk condenseChanges

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

My changes file has grown to a considerably large sum and im in need to condense it so as to continue smoothly. (`Smalltalk condenseChanges`) But when i do this i am getting an error "Invalid utf8 input detected". What should i do? I did not find adequate solution 
upon googling. Any suggestion is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This wont answer your question, but just a friendly suggestion: try to use a fresh image every day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an old bug with many reports
For example: see http://code.google.com/p/pharo/issues/detail?id=830#c2

Check if StandardFileStream is still in use in your image, specifically in the condenseChanges phase.
If yes replace it with FileStream (or MultiByteFileStream, I don't remember), retry a condenseChanges (I hope you saved a working copy of the image/changes pair) and see if it fixes the problem.

Normally, this should have been fixed in recent versions of Pharo, but since there are so many reports of the same bug, I did not took time to dig into the new bugtracker, nor into current development branch.

Comment: its using MultiByteFileStream  itself. condenseChanges is a very useful tool. So whatever problems it has, i hope its fixed. However i have condensed my changes file by doing this, and proceeding whenever debug pops up.[Smalltalk condenseChanges] on:Error do:[:e| e resume].So far it worked ok for me.

Comment: also i does update my image regularly...just to make sure that nothing gets missed out. Anyway, another concern of mine is , while tracking the issue in code.google , its said the ticket has been transferred to fog bugs, fo some wired reason i find it very difficult to view it in fogbugs, it requires login it seems , and dont know where to register to get that login...so i think i am going to be satisfied with my stupid "error block and proceed" method , at least for now

Answer (score 3):

Simply don't use `#condenseChanges`. As Uko says, save your code, get a fresh image and load your code there. Unless you are doing something special there are more reasons to use a fresh image every once in a while than not (I use a new image every couple of days).

Comment: Yes i am seriously thinking bot doing that. Thanks.